# streamed movie won't load from specific provider

Tags: iphone, objective-c, stream, video-streaming

I've wrote an App that streams a short movie over a fix URL. Everything worked fine, than the customer replaced the video with an upToDate-Version and the App went live. But since they replaced the video, it won't be streamed. I still have the adHocVersion on my device and can't reproduce the problem. I and everyone who is listed in my adHoc Provisioning Profile has the same operator, just the customer uses a different one. Is it possible that the provider is the problem? I can stream the video with 3G and even edge. Or is there maybe a difference between adHoc and live? Do I somehow have to verify an URL inside the App?

Any idea is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it really seemed to be a carrier problem. The customer uploaded a smaller video, now everythings working fine.. *shrug*..

Is there no way to delete a question like *no more answer needed* ?